# Form builder asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, formbuilder

I have a part in a application where the admin can create a form using some online form builder like [here](http://jquery-form-builder-plugin.appspot.com/). Then the admin can save the form which will create the table in the `DB` corresponding to the fields created. After that, the other users can use the form.
A simple form with text box and labels will do.
I think this is a bit vague but it is what i need now. Can anyone help me with it or any insights? It would be better if something like this is done before with any plugin.
I tried implementing above mentioned plugin but didn't have enough idea about what is posted on server after form is created.

Comment: aneal - you say above "I have a part in a application where the admin can create a form using some online form builder..." etc. can you help out by pasting the code that you have so far in this respect as it may be easier to build on that

Comment: I don't understand. As i said i have the view that uses the mentioned plugin. I am stuck on how to start. Or are you implying to post code of other parts?